# This IP can't make requests for that application. Facebook login

Tags: php, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I made an application (with facebook SDK for PHP) that was perfectly working to log-in with facebook to my website.  Some hours later it does not work, and it returns the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: This IP can't make requests for that application. thrown in /var/www/actions/facebookSDK/src/base_facebook.php on line 1279
```

There is no ip witelist in my facebook app, but it doesn't work right now!! Do you know why?